# C++ vector on heap or stack?

Tags: c++, stl, vector

I just noticed in my code that I declared a vector on the stack (instead of the heap) and then used my "set"-function to set the member variable of another class to this vector. The only problem is that after exiting my function (myFunction) the vector should be destroyed (because it is on the stack) and the reference to this vector should point to "nothing meaningful". But my code is working correctly and so I was asking myself why. Am I just lucky because the portion of the memory where the vector was, is existing because nobody deleted it until now? So it is a matter of luck if my code is not crashing?
Here is the code:

```
void myFunction() {
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> vDoubleVector = MyUtils::CreateDoubleVector(); //Creates a
   double vector (but not on heap)

   MyClass mC;
   mC.SetDoubleVector(vDoubleVector);
}

class MyClass {
   std::vector<std::vector<double>> mDoubleVector;
   void SetDoubleVector(std::vector<std::vector<double>>& aDoubleVector) {
     mDoubleVector = aDoubleVector;
   }
}
```

Comment: For the scneario you mention to occur, `mDoubleVector` would need to be a reference member, it is not in your code.Also, if it was ineed a reference member you could not set it using a setter function, You would need to initialize it in the constructor member initializer list.What you have is a member of the type `double` which has its own memory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since Luchian was faster than me, I'm going to add sensible improvement to this code:

```
void SetDoubleVector(std::vector<std::vector<double>> aDoubleVector) {
     mDoubleVector = std::move(aDoubleVector);
   }
```

Citing "rule of thumb" - *If you need to copy, do it in the interface.*

//EDIT to make the answer complete.

Your code did **copy** the vector by use of its `operator=` in `SetDoubleVector`.

Comment: Or you can just declare the mDoubleVector as reference and then the assignment operator will copy only the address. But then, of course I need to declare the vector dynamically

Comment: That's a powerful accusation... +1

Comment: It wouldn't be a reference - references can't just "hang" in space - they have to be properly initialized from the beginning.

Comment: Ah yes, you are right. This was probably the reason I did not declare it as reference

Comment: Well, if you don't really need to copy, consider using `shared_ptr`

Comment: I am actually doing it every in my code, by using std::shared_ptr (not boost ones. By the way what is the difference?), but in this case I had a very small vector of a couple of doubles and I just let it unchanged

Comment: [Let Me SO that for you](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=difference+between+std%3A%3Ashared_ptr+and+boost%3A%3Ashared_ptr)

Answer (score 3):

There is no reference to the `vector`, the class has a **copy** of it.

Comment: But I am passing it by reference. Or do you mean the assignment mDoubleVector = aDoubleVector; makes a copy

Comment: @ISTB yes. You are passing by reference, but `=` assigns `aDoubleVector` to your member (which already exists)

Comment: I'm not upvoting it until you stop stealing newbie questions from me :P

Comment: @ISTB of course, in your example, both go out of scope at the same time.